# Very strange double titlebar

Tags: applications, release-juno

Slic3r (https://slic3r.org/) is the first app I've seen do this on Elementary. Basically it's showing 2 titlebars. Any suggestions?

Details:

- When the window is not fullscreen, you can see an application window with some of the desktop wallpaper repeated in it, then a smaller nested application window inside of it

  - When the window is fullscreen, the desktop wallpaper duplication issue disappears but there are still 2 titlebars displayed.

[image: Wndowed]

[image: Fullscreen]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a known issue. It only occurs with applications that request legacy window decorations (titlebars, borders, etc...). I'm part of the elementary team and I'm looking into a fix, but it's not a quick easy fix.

In the mean time, there's a workaround where you can run the app from the terminal like so:

```
GTK_CSD=0 slic3r
```

You'll need to replace `slic3r` with the actual executable name of Slic3r or the path to the executable if that's not correct.

However, this workaround sometimes causes other issues like open/save dialogs not opening.

Further information can be found here:
https://github.com/elementary/gala/issues/244

Comment: Worked like a champ, thanks! Menu entry all edited and working great.

Comment: Worked also for Firefox Developer Edition 87. Thanks.